# PHP - How to check for element each loop?

Tags: php, xml, loops, dom

I am using the below loop to parse an XML file.

```
$link = $item->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
$image = $item->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
```

However, Some times the XML item doesn't have an `'enclosure'` element and my entire page fails with the below error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
```

How can I check for the element each loop and replace the $image variable with a static string if it doesn't exist?

Comment: $item is not object type that's why error is showing.

Comment: Use xpath instead, it's easier to deal with in case the result is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use xpath for that. With **DOMDocument** and **DOMXPath** you can highly benefit from the [`DOMXPath::evaluate` method](http://php.net/domxpath.evaluate) as you can fetch string values directly. In case the element queried for does not exists, you'll get an empty string (you can also check existance with `count()` which returns `0` in case a node was not found).

Example:

```
$item  = $doc->getElementsByTagName('itme')->item(0);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

echo "link.....: ", $xpath->evaluate('string(.//link)', $item), "\n";
echo "enclosure: ", $xpath->evaluate('string(.//enclosure[@url])', $item), "\n";
```

I create some example XML

```
<feed-me>
    <item>
        <link>http://nytimes.com/2004/12/07FEST.html</link>
        <actor class="foo" xml:space="preserve"> </actor>
    </item>
</feed-me>
```

and the output is

```
link.....: http://nytimes.com/2004/12/07FEST.html
enclosure:
```

As this example shows, the first xpath expression evaluated to the text-content of the `<link>` element. The second expression evalutes to an empty string because the attribute does not exists.

The problem that obtaining an attribute from a non-existing element as you have it when you access the objects in PHP code

```
$item->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
                                             ^               ^
                                             |               |
                                   there is no item at       |
                                  index 0, this is NULL      |
                                                             |
                                                         NULL has no
                                                     getAttribute method
                                                        = FATAL ERROR
```

With the xpath expression on the other hand

```
 string(.//enclosure[@url])
```

the inner expression `.//enclosure[@url]` returns an empty nodelist and the [`string()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) returns `""` (empty string) for it. Otherwise it returns the string-value of the first node (that is in document order) within that nodelist.

All in all this makes it really easy to obtain the information from the document in a stable manner. You have to learn some little xpath language however. But we have it well supported here as well on Stackoverlow.

Example in full (and [online demo to play around](https://eval.in/308604)):

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP - How to check for element each loop?
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/29452042/367456
 */

$buffer = <<<XML
<feed-me>
    <item>
        <link>http://nytimes.com/2004/12/07FEST.html</link>
        <actor class="foo" xml:space="preserve"> </actor>
    </item>
</feed-me>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($buffer);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$item = $doc->getElementsByTagName('itme')->item(0);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

echo "link.....: ", $xpath->evaluate('string(.//link)', $item), "\n";
echo "enclosure: ", $xpath->evaluate('string(.//enclosure[@url])', $item), "\n";

$item->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answers. All working well now. Cheers.

Comment: Yours cheers, too. Read a bit in the manual about this new function in your tool-chest. It's especially good to know about the context-node for such parsing jobs in (foreach) loops.